# attempting to parse an EDI file and sum invoice totals

Tags: java, parsing, edi

I've managed to extract the numbers I'm looking for but (probably because I haven't used Java since college) I can't add the numbers to get a "total" and count for the EDI file. The output shows that I am collecting each invoice total as a double but when I attempt to add them it is resetting the number each time the while loop runs, if I place it outside of the loop it doesn't recognize my variable.

Here is my code

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("\\Edi810o311214.dat")))
{
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine())!= null)
    { 
    //eliminates lines that do not begin with "total"
    String lineEval = line.substring(0,5);
    if (lineEval.equals("Total"))
    {   
        //extracts total invoice field from line
        String totalValue = line.substring(12,26);
        double totalValueNum = Double.parseDouble(totalValue);

        //shows output for testing purposes (will remove)
        System.out.println(totalValueNum);    
        double total = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        total += totalValueNum;
        counter++;


    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "lines that do not being with total"?  If you were parsing EDI and want to accumulate totals for all interchanges (Assuming multiple 810s in the file), you'd want to get the value in the TDS segment.  Is this already a translated file (meaning X12 to another format)?

Answer (score 0):

It would stand to reason that I would look at this for hours and then answer my own question within a minute or two of finally giving up and posting it

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("\\Edi810o311214.dat")))
{
    int counter = 0;
    double total = 0;
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine())!= null)

    { 
    //eliminates lines that do not begin with "total"
    String lineEval = line.substring(0,5);
    if (lineEval.equals("Total"))

    {   
        counter++;
        //extracts total invoice field from line
        String totalValue = line.substring(12,26);
        double totalValueNum = Double.parseDouble(totalValue);
        total += totalValueNum;
        //shows output for testing purposes (will remove)
        System.out.println(totalValueNum);    






    }

    }
    System.out.println(counter);
    System.out.println(total);

    }

}
```